# How to hide a validator's error text when the validator is initially enabled

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I've got the following javascript code, which enables a bunch of validators.

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%=AddressValidator.ClientID %>"), true);
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%=CityValidator.ClientID %>"), true);
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("<%=CountryValidator.ClientID %>"), true);
```

My problem is that when the validators are enabled with the above code, the error message (i.e. the validation text) is displayed. How can I hide the error message just for this instance when they're being enabled?

Comment: Can you show your ValidatorEnable function?

Comment: It's not a user-defined function, you can just call it.

Comment: @DotNET  but the logic is inside the ValidatorEnable() method, which is available on clientside as a normal Javascript function. So you might be able to identify what this function is doing etc. Which responsibility has the second (boolean) parameter in your func. calls?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to enable it without validating:

```
document.getElementById("<%=AddressValidator.ClientID %>").enabled = true;
```

Because [`ValidatorEnable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) internally looks like:

```
function ValidatorEnable(val, enable) { 
    val.enabled = (enable != false); 
    ValidatorValidate(val); 
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid(); 
}
```

http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.de/2009/04/calling-validator-controls-from.html